# Creating a list of lists with consecutive numbers

Tags: python

I am looking for a convenient way to create a list of lists for which the lists within the list have consecutive numbers. So far I only came up with a very unsatisfying brute-typing force solution (yeah right, I just use python for a few weeks now):

```
block0 = []
...
block4 = []

blocks = [block0,block1,block2,block3,block4]
```

I appreciate any help that works with something like `nrBlocks = 5`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not clear what consecutive numbers you're talking about, but your code translates into the following idiomatic Python:

```
[[] for _ in range(4)]          # use xrange in python-2.x
```

Comment: I wanted to access the sublists via name (i.e., block3), but after thinking about it a second time i realize that accessing them as block[3] is basically the same. As each sublist still can have a different length and its not an array as in e.g., C.

Comment: Even in C, you could have an array of pointers to differently-sized arrays.

Comment: You're off by one. You want range(5)

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it this way. Put it in `blocks` in the first place:

```
blocks = [
  [ ... ],
  [ ... ],
  [ ... ],
  [ ... ]
]
```