# Add to array consecutive numbers

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm

This is my first question to SO, I hope to get it right. In PHP (if you can't, python or pseudo language is also okay), Given an array of n elements:

```
old_array = [1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 20, 21, 23, 29]
```

I need to add to a new array consecutive numbers, if it is not a consecutive number add only that value to a new array:

```
new_array = [ [1,2,3],
              [5],
              [7,8,9]
              [20,21]
              [23],
              [29]
            ]
```

Here on SO, i found these related topics, but can't get it to work.

1. [Creating a list of lists with consecutive numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408452/creating-a-list-of-lists-with-consecutive-numbers)
2. [Python finding n consecutive numbers in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2927213/python-finding-n-consecutive-numbers-in-a-list)
3. [Find the sum of consecutive whole numbers w/o using loop in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2843052/find-the-sum-of-consecutive-whole-numbers-w-o-using-loop-in-javascript)

---

The code that wasn't working is on the version history, I removed it because it's having formatting problems.

Thanks all, and especially Juan, mistabell and Axsuul for the providing the correct answer.

Comment: Is this a real problem? It looks like homework.

Comment: Can't get it to work you say? Show us what you've come up with so far and maybe we can spot the problem.

Comment: @Marcelo Cantos Yes. Basically I'm trying to put up a webapp, but I'm stuck on this problem (I'm a UI designer, and I'm starting only now to programm).

Comment: Damn it. I'm having formatting problems, please some hint.

Comment: I think it'd be simpler if you made `new_array = [[1,2,3],[5],[7,8,9],[20,21],[23],[29]]`.  Making single items not be in an array introduces an inconsistency.

Comment: Yes, thanks, in the code I'm trying to write it should work like that. (updated the original question, thanks)

Comment: On a side note, you *really* should remove all those calls to `count` it's a perfomance killer, and thus, considered a bad practice in PHP to call it inside loops (even when checking the loop condition).

Comment: Yes I know, it's just temporary (I removed my code, it's having formatting problems, see the version history).

Comment: This is the same as the groupBy function in Haskell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best I can came up with is:

```
function subsequenceArray($values) {
    $res = array();
    $length = count($values);
    if (0 == $length) {
        return $res;
    }
    $last = 0;
    $res[$last] = array($values[0]);
    for ($i = 1; $i < $length; $i++) {
        if ($values[$i] == $values[$i-1] + 1) {
            $res[$last][] = $values[$i];
        } else {
            $res[++$last] = array($values[$i]);
        }
    }
    return $res;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
function buildPairedArray($oldArray) {
$newArray = array();
$i = 0;

foreach ($oldArray as $index => $value) {
    if ($index == 0) {
        $newArray[$i][] = $value;
        continue;

    }

    if ($oldArray[$index] == $oldArray[$index-1]+1) { // consecutive
        $newArray[$i][] = $value;

    } else {
        $newArray[++$i][] = $value;

    }
}

return $newArray;
```

}

Testing it

```
$old = array(1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 20, 21, 23, 29);
print_r(buildPairedArray($old));
```

Results:

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
        )

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 5
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 7
        [1] => 8
        [2] => 9
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 20
        [1] => 21
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => 23
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [0] => 29
    )
```

)

Comment: I'm having formatting problems too. I tried with the code html tag, but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed, feels like a standard algorithm design question to me.  Eagleal, have you tried thinking through the psuedo-code for this, and then converting that to PHP?  How would you tell mathematically (in your head) if two given numbers are consecutive?  Hint: The answer involves subtraction, or even addition, and the number 1.